# Foreign Key Creation Error

Tags: mysql

When i create FOREIGN KEY,

ALTER TABLE `test_table` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`stateid`) REFERENCES `state` (`stateid` );

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dbname.#sql-*' (errno: 150)

The above error will shown ..share solution for this ?

Comment: Does `test_table.stateid` and `state.stateid` have the same type?

Comment: Are you sure of field names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign Keys and MySQL Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814392/foreign-keys-and-mysql-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error:**

> 1st Table - primary key - integer field
>
> 2nd Table - Foreign key field name - unsigned int

**Solution:**
Both key fields datatypes should be same